# like and subscribe button conflict?

Tags: facebook-like, subscription

I have a like button on my website, which has a corresponding FB page and App. The like button is functional and has been for a while. I recently decided to add a subscribe button to my webpage, so that users could get updates on our content, posted directly to their wall, if they chose to. However, although I have generated the subscribe button code directly from the FB developers page with the correct App ID, the subscribe button does not show up or function when the code is inserted into my webpage. I am not sure if this is a conflict with the pre-existing like button. I have tried all 3 variations of the subscribe button, but none of them are showing up when tested locally or on the server.

So, first, please clarify if the subscribe button would indeed allow subscribers to get updates from our FB page that they subscribe to. And if that is the case, why can I not activate it on my website?

Comment: What errors are happening?  Anything in the javascript console?  Does the XFBML get changed into iframes correctly?